# Issues with dialog input and fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I don't know if the issue is related to fullcalendar or not, probably not, but not 100% sure.
I have 2 hiddens forms shown in the first case when an event is clicked and in the other case when I select times to create an event.

These are the two forms (it's the same with 2 less button).

```
    <div id="eventContent" title="Détail de la tache" style="display:none;">
        <form id="form_infos">
            <label for="title">Titre:</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title_input"/>
            Début: <span id="startTime"></span><br>
            Fin: <span id="endTime"></span><br><br>
            <label for="eventInfos">Description:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="eventInfos" id="eventInfos"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-success" />
            <input type="button" value="Copier" id="copier" class="btn btn-success" />
            <input type="reset" value="Supprimer" class="btn btn-danger" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="eventContent_create" title="Détail de la tache" style="display:none;">
        <form id="form_infos_create">
            <label for="title_create">Titre:</label><input type="text" name="title_create" id="title_input_create"/>
            Début: <span id="startTime_create"></span><br>
            Fin: <span id="endTime_create"></span><br><br>
            <label for="eventInfos_create">Description:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="eventInfos_create" id="eventInfos_create"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-success" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

The issue is just on what is print inside the field title and eventInfos.

Step 1: While none events have been created by select, if I click existing events, the dialog shows and the input are well filled.
Then I want to create a new event, so I select a timelapse, the form in dialog shows himself and is well filled empty.

So, the step 1 is ok.

But then comes the step 2, once the event is created, each time I will open a dialog, either it is by clicking an existing dialog or selecting timelapse for creating a new one, then the inputs will be filled all the time with the last created events.

I can't understand why. I hope you will be able to help.

Js side clicking on event

```
        eventClick: function(event, element) {
             event_save=event;
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            if(event_save!=undefined){
                event=event_save;
            }
            element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');

            element.click(function() {
                console.log("open render");
                $("#title_input").attr({value :event.title});
                $("#title").html(event.title);
                $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
                $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
                $("#eventInfos").html(event.description);
                $("#eventContent").dialog('open');
            });
```

Js side selecting timelapse

```
     select: function(start, end,jsEvent) {
                var eventData = {
                    title: "",
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    description: ""
                  };
                $("#startTime_create").html(moment(start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
                $("#endTime_create").html(moment(end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
                //$("#title_input").removeAttr("value");
                $("#title_input_create").attr({value: " "});
                $("#eventInfos_create").html(" ");
                event_save=eventData;
                console.log("create");
                $("#eventContent_create").dialog('open');
    }
```

I'm wonderring if this is not due to `element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');` missing on select but I have really no idea. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Here is the screen of what is happening...the html is fine...but the output didn't seems to correspond

```
                console.log($("#title_input_create"));
                $("#eventContent_create").dialog('open');
```

[Screen of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrBKl.png)

Comment: can you create fiddle for issue?

Comment: Why are you adding an extra `element.click(function() {` on each event, when there is already the "eventClick" callback which you can use for this. Not sure if that's the cause of your issue but it could potentially be related, and it definitely seems a bit unnecessary. I also suspect that passing round the `event_save` global is not helping. If you structure your code properly this should not be necessary. I can't see all your code to see where else you use it, but you should aim to get rid of it, because it's probably polluting things

Comment: @ADyson Because I saw render was called many times and not only on click but yeah indeed I can just work inside the .click you right....so I made the change. But still the issue remains the same.

Comment: eventRender is called once for each individual event, yes. So if you have 20 events it will run 20 times. Anyway I think next you should work towards removing the need for the `event_save` global object, I think this is probably confusing things.

Comment: @ADyson I understand what you are saying and I will probably do that at some point, but event_save has nothing to do in this particular case. When i am on select I open eventContent_create dialog box. But in this case event_save is never used to fill the inputs, `$("#title_input_create").attr({value: " "});` The real issue is why the value attr isn't taking " " after step 1...even if the code is executed.

Comment: @ADyson In order to complete my response, if I have used this event_save it's because I haven't managed to find which js events correspond to the select...element.select is not working. So I had to somehow store the event selected.

Comment: I just add a screen for the issue

Comment: Try and use `$("#title_input_create").val("");` instead

Comment: Also, "f I have used this event_save it's because I haven't managed to find which js events correspond to the select."...it's a drag and drop operation, written in code, it's no particular JS event, but probably a combination of several (mousedown, mouseup etc) and some custom code. I don't see why that's relevant though, nor do I see why you need to do `event_save=eventData;` at all...what is the purpose of it? Surely you can just wait until the form in the dialog is submitted, and then you can get all the data for the new event from the fields in the dialog.

Comment: @ADyson actually I'm not sure it's a drag and drop...drag his catch the object and move the entire object...but the select is just "extending" the object.

Comment: it's not what fullcalendar calls dragging (by this they mean moving an existing event), but still the action you do with the mouse is click, hold, drag, release. That's what I meant

Comment: @ADyson `$("#title_input_create").val("");`seems to be working...I don't understand why there is an issue with my syntax :( But ploblem solved. Thanks. Can you move your comment into the response section in order to set the issue as solved ?

Comment: @MinirockAkeru I have added an answer with an explanation of why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.val()` to alter the value of the field.
Change

```
 $("#title_input_create").attr({value: " "});
```

to

```
$("#title_input_create").val("");
```

Explanation:

See this demo using your original syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/xk1shu9q/3/ . If you click the button without typing into the box, then it will clear the field. However if you type a new value in before you click, the field will then not be cleared.

This is to do with how the DOM works for input elements - `.attr()` will change the original attribute text in the written HTML, but this is not the same as the current *value* of the field held in the browser's memory - this is held in a separate `value` field attached to the element. Altering the `.value` property on a native DOM element object, or using jQuery's `.val()` on a jQuery object will modify the current field value, rather than its original value.

Comment: No problem. Note that some attributes can be modified using .attr() no problem, since they don't have any other functionality associated with them, and you can always rely on them. But watch out for those attributes, such as value, which are really only used when the page is first loaded.